# Does Nina Simone play the piano on "I loves you Porgy" (studio version)?

Tags: jazz

Is Nina Simone accompanying herself on that track, and if not who plays the piano?

I've heard from someone that she does indeed accompany herself and I've seen her do it in live videos, but the comping on that track is of such high quality that I have a hard time believing she could be playing that while singing.

I've looked for this info online but couldn't find it...

EDIT: I'm not sure this is the right SE to ask this question. Apologies if it isn't, in which case I would really appreciate being redirected to the right place. Thank you.

Comment: Nina Simone was an extraordinary pianist with classical training --she became a singer to supplement her piano playing, not the other way around.  Given that, it's unlikely someone else was accompanying her.  You might enjoy the recent documentary "What Happened, Miss Simone?" which details her life and career.  There's an amazing scene late in the movie where she plays one song on the piano (classical) and sings a different one at the same time (jazz/blues).

Comment: Here's the song I was referencing (since you said you've already seen the live version of *I loves you Porgy*) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8r0EcX4Ae4Q

Comment: @ChrisSunami Thank you for the info and the video link, that was amazing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that Nina Simone is the [only credited pianist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Girl_Blue_(album)#Personnel) on the album on which "I Loves You Porgy" first appears, her debut album *Little Girl Blue*, it's highly likely that she was accompanying herself on the album. Although album credits can be inaccurate, whether on purpose or not, the sole credit and the fact that she still aspired to be a concert pianist at that time leads me to believe that she played piano on it.

Comment: Thank you, given what you said it does seem extremely likely she is the one playing.